# iPhone SDK: UIButtons in UIScrollView - Resize Scroll View to Fit all Non Hidden Buttons

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I have 7 UIButtons in a UIScrollView. The top 3 UIButtons can be either hidden or visible depending on if statements in code. Meaning there are 8 possibilities of the 3 UIButtons displaying.
The problem i'm having is getting the UIScrollView to adjust its content size so that there are no "empty" looking spaces in it. For example if the middle UIButton is hidden but the ones above and below it are visible, there is an empty space left. 
Is there any way make all the buttons fit one underneath the other in the scrollview without any gaps?

I have tried this code but it didn't work:

```
if([[facilities objectAtIndex:0]intValue] == 1) {

        facilitiesButton.hidden = NO;



    }

    if([[ListingsEnabled objectAtIndex:0]intValue]==1) {

        ListingsBtn.hidden = NO;
    } 

    if([[OffersEnabled objectAtIndex:0]intValue]==1) {

        OffersBtn.hidden = NO;
    }

    CGFloat scrollViewHeight = 0.0f;
    self.DetailScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;       
    self.DetailScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    for (UIView* view in self.DetailScrollView.subviews)
    {
        if (!view.hidden)
        {
            CGFloat y = view.frame.origin.y;
            CGFloat h = view.frame.size.height;
            if (y + h > scrollViewHeight)
            {
                scrollViewHeight = h + y;
            }
        }
    }
    self.DetailScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;
    self.DetailScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;

    [self.DetailScrollView setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(self.DetailScrollView.frame.size.width, scrollViewHeight))];
```

Comment: I think the problem is that you have to adjust the position of every UIButton if you want to avoid a gap. You can of course calculate the height of the uiscrollview's contentsize, but the buttons will not adjust if you change the size of the content. I thought about another approach. What about a Tableview instead of the scrollview? Perhaps you have got an array of uibuttons and you adjust the numberOfRowsInSection to all your non-hidden UIButtons. Then you return only cells with the non-hidden buttons on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @Andy commented, you need to position the actual buttons, not just change the scroll view size. A Table View may be indeed the way to go, but for 7 buttons that may be overkill. Here's a snippet that will loop through the buttons and update their positions based on visibility. I omitted the scroll view because it doesn't seem necessary, but if you need them in a scroll view that will update i can edit the code, just let me know.

```
/////////////////////
///// USES ARC //////
/////////////////////

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    allButtons = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Create 7 buttons and randomly hide some
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect]; 
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50);
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Button %i", i+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(randomizeButtons:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:button];

        button.hidden = arc4random_uniform(2)-1 > 0;

        [allButtons addObject:button];
    }

    [self updateButtonLayout];
}

-(void)updateButtonLayout
{
    // position buttons based on visiblity

    CGRect lastButtonFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    int verticalPadding = 10;

    for(UIButton *btn in allButtons)
    {
        if(!btn.hidden)
        {
            btn.frame = CGRectMake(lastButtonFrame.origin.x, lastButtonFrame.origin.y+lastButtonFrame.size.height+verticalPadding, btn.frame.size.width, btn.frame.size.height);

            lastButtonFrame = btn.frame;
        }
    }
}

-(void)randomizeButtons:(UIButton *)btn
{
    // Randomize the visiblity of the buttons and update the interface

    for(UIButton *btn in allButtons)
    {
        btn.hidden = arc4random_uniform(2)-1 > 0;
    }

    [self updateButtonLayout];
}
```